# Plot a CDF chart by Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, math, charts, plot

I'm not quite sure if I can ask this question here or on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/),

I want to know how can I plot a [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) chart out of my excel data.
My data is something like this (my real data have 22424 records):

```
1   2.39E-05
1   2.39E-05
1   2.39E-05
2   4.77E-05
2   4.77E-05
2   4.77E-05
4   9.55E-05
4   9.55E-05
4   9.55E-05
4   9.55E-05
4   9.55E-05
4   9.55E-05
8   0.000190931
8   0.000190931
```

Comment: @belis first column: output degree of my graph, Second Column: outputDegree/AllOutPutDegree

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean by "degree"

Comment: @belis I think it's not important what exactly my column is, the important thins is that 'SUM(my second column)=1' and my first column don't have a normal distribution

Comment: Just trying to understand the meaning of your data, why the numbers are repeated, etc. Sorry if that bothers you.

Comment: @beli I can do more coding to eliminate repeated data and combine them, but I wan know that excel have any feature to convenient my work and plot CDF from this data

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why your numbers in the second column are duplicating its value from bin to bin. I also don't understand why you have three ones and three twos, and the values on the second column are different. In short: I don't understand your table. Let's assume it's my fault and hope you get a good answer.

Comment: @beli, I try to explain what exactly my table is, I create a graph and I want to plot a CDF of outdegree of my graph, so the column one is my graph's node outdegree(the reason why it's repeated is that I parse my graph with python and print every outdegree of node in my file) the second column is outdegree of this node divide by outdegree of my all node in grafph (so sum of my second column become one (for using in CDF)) sorry for my bad english

Comment: So if you have node 1 with three "outs" and node 2 with three "outs", Why they have different numbers in the second column?

Comment: @belis I think I explain badly, in my table there isn't any node output just outdegree and it's distribution, so as you can see all have the same data id outdegree is 1 all it's distribution is 2.39E-05
 and so on. and as I said before I calculate Distribution like this (outdegree_of_one_node/SUM(outDegree_of_all_node))

Comment: @belis Sorry if I bother you :(, I do every thing you said I draw Chart but I think Column D have some problem because it's go above 1 :( (some thing bad happen in delete duplicate) sum of column C is 1 but something wrong in column D

Comment: @Am1rr3zA I repeated the procedure and everything is OK. How much above one? Could be rounding errors?

Comment: @belis here are sum of all four columns (A:22308    B:0.532410501    C:0.999999901    D:16283.91822)

Comment: What is the last number in column D?

Comment: last number in Column D is 128.0621279

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `NORMDIST` function and set the final parameter to true:

As an example, suppose I have 20 data points from 0.1 to 2.0 in increments of 0.1 i.e. 0.1, 0.2, 0.3...2.0.

Now suppose that the mean of that dataset is 1.0 and the standard deviation is 0.2.

To get the CDF plot I can use the following formula for each of my values:

```
=NORMDIST(x, 1.0, 0.2, TRUE) -- where x is 0.1, 0.2, 0.3...2.0
```

[image]

---

To remove duplicate entries from your data and sum values that are the same you can use the following code.

1. In excel, place you data in sheet1, starting in cell A1
2. Press `ALT + F11` to open VBE
3. Now `Insert > Module` to place a module in the editor
4. Cut and paste code below into module
5. Place cursor anywhere in `RemoveDuplicates` and Press `F5` to run the code

As a result, your unique, summed results will appear in Sheet2 in your workbook.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:B" & GetLastRow(Range("A1")))

    rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    Dim filteredRng As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    Set filteredRng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & GetLastRow(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")))

    For Each cl In filteredRng
        cl.Offset(0, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rng.Columns(1), cl.Value, rng.Columns(2))
    Next cl
End Sub

Function GetLastRow(rng As Range) As Long
    GetLastRow = rng.End(xlDown).Row
End Function
```

Comment: How did you guess the distribution is Normal?

Comment: In my example I was simply showing a stylised example of how to to do CDF plot with assumed mean and sd...in real world you would need to test for normality, variance assumptions etc.

Comment: @Remn as you can see in my sample data posted I have some repeated data in my value column how can I pre-process them? and also I have not Normal distribution in my data

Comment: @Remnan Tanx for your answer but I am newbie in excel can you explain more how can do this? also note when you want unify my value must change the second column and put then sum of them (I mean instead of I have 3 "1        2.39E-05" I must have one "1      7.17e-05")

Comment: @Am1rr3za @Remm Remove Duplicates is a function available in the ribbon, isn't it? (under {data})

Comment: @Belisarius - I have not come across 'ribbon' before? Is it an add-in?

Comment: @Rem http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-the-ribbon-HA010089895.aspx

Comment: @Remn I did it but I get (Run-Time Error'9' Subscribe out of range) I must tell you I have Microsoft Excel 2011 for Mac OS X. I get the error for this line : rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), Unique:=True

Comment: @Am1rr3zA - I assume you have a worksheet called "Sheet2" in your workbook? It worked on Excel 2003 (Windows)...

Comment: @Belisarius - lol at 'ribbon'. I am still old school on 2003!

Comment: @Rem So you have to use VBA for "delete duplicates" :D

Comment: @Remn Tanx so much I can solve my problem with combination of your solution and @belis Solution

Answer (score 6):

This answer is how to create an 'empirical distribution function', which is what many people really have in mind (myself included) when they say CDF... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function

Assuming the second column of the sample data starts in cell B1, in cell C1, type:

```
=SUM(IF($B$1:$B$14<=B1,1,0))/COUNT($B$1:$B$14)
```

then press Shift+Enter, to enter it as an array formula. It will now look like this in the formula bar:

```
{=SUM(IF($B$1:$B$14<=B1,1,0))/COUNT($B$1:$B$14)}
```

Copy the cell down to cover C1:C14. Then make Scatter plot with B1:B14 as X, C1:C14 as Y. It will show four points.

- Don't need to sort or remove duplicates
- Use range names, or take advantage of Excel table capabilities, to manage the input ranges more automatically
- It is a single-cell array formula, so depending on how you copy-and-paste, you will get a message "Cannot change part of an array". If you use Copy-Paste, copy cell C1, then select cells C2:c14 and Paste.
- Ideally, the graph should be presented as a step function, but I didn't have time to figure out any way (good or bad) to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see if I understood your problem.  Assuming Excel 2007 and up. Assuming your data is in columns A and B.

**Step 1**

Use this formula in cell C1:

```
=B1*COUNTIF(A:A,A1)
```

And this formula in cell D1:

```
=SUM($C$1:C1)
```

and copy both formulas down to the end of data.

**Step 2**

Select the four columns.
Select in Ribbon Data->Delete Duplicates
Uncheck Columns B,C and D

**Step 3**

Select Columns A and D.
Select in Ribbon Insert->Scatter->Line

Is this what you want to achieve?

HTH!

Comment: @belis it's exactly what I want except that I want that instead of I have 3 "1 2.39E-05" I must have one "1 7.17e-05" (mean I don't want just simply remove duplicate need a little process too :( )

Comment: @Am1rr3zA Edited. Please take a look.

Comment: @Belis in Step 2 it tells me that not found any duplicate is it right? or I must select some of columns instead of all 4?

Comment: @Am1rr3zA You have to select all four, then goto data->deleteduplicates. There a dialog appear, showing all columns. UNCHECK the last three, leaving checked only the first column.

Comment: @belis Tanx so much I can solve my problem with combination of your solution and @Remn Solution, but I accept @beli Solution because he has lower Reputation than you and want help him to grow faster (just little +15), but your answer teach me lots of excel tricks tanx a lot.

Comment: @beli I understand what you mean but My solution was combination of your solutions and I don't decide which of them are more complete.