# Creating a Variable Curve from Linear Data

Tags: excel, math, filemaker, vba

My end goal is to distribute items into different discounts for sales. For example I may have 1000 items in an up-to 20% off sale. I am trying to come up with a way to cluster more items towards a discount, say 15%. So the discount distribution is a curve, with the peak number of items around 15% and less items at the extreme low and high discounts.

I want this to work for many different sales- number of items included will change and the discount ranges will change. I may have 25,000 items in a 10-40% off sale.
Variables:

```
L = Low Discount
H = High Discount 
S = Discount Spread (H - L)
I = Item Count
D = Discount Sread (S / I)
C = ClusterPeak, where I want the most items
```

All items are ranked and sorted. Using Excel, Excel VBA or FileMaker I am sure there is math thing I can throw at this to make work.

Using the first example of 1000 items in an up-to 20% off sale. (starting at 1%)

```
L = .01
H = .2
S = .19
I = 1000
D = .00019
C = .15
R = Current Row or Record.
```

To get linear, evenly distributed discounts, I know I can do this-

(R * S) + L or (1 * .00019) + .1

This gets me .01019, .01038... The 1000th item gets .2, or 20%. This works regardless of the discounts and items count. Yay!

But I am stumped on how to cluster more items around a discount in a smooth curve. I have tried throwing LOG and standard deviation at the problem in various uses but obivously it didn't work or I wouldn't be here.

Sorry if this is miscategorized or poorly explained. It is very hard explaning what you don't know. Is there a better name or description for what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use a CDF like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561920/plot-a-cdf-chart-by-microsoft-excel you can shift where you want the mean `\mu`

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/media/File:Normal_Distribution_CDF.svg